# Custom counter when link is clicked in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wpdb

I would like to monitor the number of times a user clicks the hyperlink assigned with a class name link_counter. I'm using jQuery and PHP to do this, for example:

```
    $('.link_counter').click(function() {   
    <?php 
     //Retrieve the current count from dB

    @countdata = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT counter FROM $mycustomtable WHERE my_user_id=%d",$user_id));

    //increment counter

    $updated_count=$countdata+1;

    //update back the dB table

    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $mycustomtable SET counter=%d WHERE my_user_id=%d",$updated_count,$user_id));
    ?>

    });
```

It works well. However the only issue is when there are more than one link page having the same class. If I click on the another link on that the same page, the count would not be updated.

How do I modify my code and my query to update this count without using AJAX and not reloading the page? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing. you're registering a click when this bit of code is printed to the page, not when the link is clicked- you can't execute php within javascript.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14453590, please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree the only way that I can do this with AJAX. I have modified my scripts to include AJAX and it is now working. Thanks.